# $index values within nested ng-repeat with sequence if inner ng-repeat array is different length

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using nested ng-repeat in angualrjs and the inner ng-repeat array length is different. So index does not show in sequence.
I need the output of index in sequence. I have attached a screenshot of the output.

Can anyone help me?

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
           <th>#($index)</th>
           <th>L #</th>
           <th>C Name</th>
           <th>A #</th>
           <th>F P</th>                         
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="d in displayData" >   
        <tr ng-repeat="a in d.f_p track by $index" > 
            <td>{{($parent.$index*d.f_p.length)+($index+1)}}</td>
            <td>{{d.lId}}</td>
            <td>{{d.cName}}</td>
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{a}}</td>      
        </tr>       
 </tbody>
 </table>

$scope.displayData=[{"lId": "369857","cName": "ABCD","f_p":0.04401,0.04402,0.04403]},{"lId": "369858","cName": "BCDE",          "f_p":[0.04401,0.04402,0.04403,0.04404]},{"lId": "369859","cName": "CDEF",                  "f_p":[0.04401,0.04402,0.04403,0.04404,0.04405]}];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle, because your json object seems not valid

Comment: what are we supposed to notice in the screenshot? problem is not clear and neither is what you expect to differ

Answer (score 0):

this is the only valid case for ng-init:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="d in displayData" ng-init="$outerIndex = $index">
```